# Foreach loop throwing an error I don't exactly understand

Tags: java, methods, foreach, error-handling, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm relatively new to Java and I'm having a problem with a foreach loop in a method I'm writing. I keep getting an astronomical index out-of-bounds error but I have no idea where it's coming from.

Here's my code.

```
public static int smallestInt(int[] arr)
{
    int minVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    
    for (int value : arr)
    {
        if (arr[value] < minVal)
        {
            minVal = arr[value];
        }
    }
    if (arr.length == 0)
    {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    
    return minVal;

}
```

The error thrown states:  Index 88 out of bounds for length 6

Any help will be appreciated, as I have been stuck on this for quite a while

Comment: please share the stack trace. what line is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 1):

A `for-each` loop access an array value with a ***hidden** index*. This

```
if (arr[value] < minVal)
{
    minVal = arr[value];
}
```

Should be

```
if (value < minVal)
{
    minVal = value;
}
```

**or**

```
minVal = Math.min(minVal, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try applying this to your array

```
    public static int smallestInt(int[] arr)
{
    int minVal = arr[0];
    
    
    for (int value : arr)
    {
        if (arr[value] < minVal)
        {
            minVal = arr[value];
        }
    }
    
    return minVal;
}
```

the array value will never be less than the Integer.MAX_VALUE because you are setting the minVal variable to the highest number possible that can be stored as a int which is 2147483647